# Number of files currently indexed

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

To lower CPU usage, I'm trying to exclude some folders (e.g. `node_modules`) and file types to be indexed by Sublime. I don't know though if my changes in settings are in effect.

How do I find out how many files Sublime currently have in index?

Answer (score 1):

When ST reindexes your files, you can see how many files are indexed by looking in the Help menu -> Indexing Status...

> ```
> indexing [job 1]: spawning 2 workers to process 173 / 173 files
> indexing [job 1]: indexed 173 files
> ```

[image: ST indexing status]

Unfortunately the log entries aren't timestamped, but the latest entries are added at the bottom.

Comment: Great! But is there any way to check that file number when Sublime is not indexing as well?

Comment: I don't believe so - [there is currently no API that exposes this information](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/api-suggestions/20640/19?u=kingkeith), so all you can do is trigger a reindex (perhaps by closing and reopening the project)